# How to efficiently find identical indices in multiple dataframes

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dataframe, symmetric-difference

I have a process that collects reports generated throughout the week and consolidates the collection to eliminate identical reports.

I've written a function that identifies identical reports by finding those that have identical indices, then it excludes all but one of those that are identical and moves on. While it works fine for 5000-10,000 reports, it starts to take a serious amount of time to process through, say, 50,000+ reports, which as time goes on will be more and more common.

It would be nice if I could pre-emptively eliminate the reports and so avoid this step, but the process of generating the reports doesn't allow for that. So, I want to find a way to make this or a similar function more efficient.

The code is below:

```
def report_diff_index(self,dnc_data,folders):
    master_report_dict, master_val_dict = self.report_orderer(folders)
    sorts = self.report_sorter(dnc_data,master_report_dict)
    keys = [k for k in sorts.keys()]
    consolidated_sorts = keys
    print('Original Report Size: ', len(consolidated_sorts))
    for k in keys:
        if k in consolidated_sorts:
            for j in keys[keys.index(k)+1:]:
                if j in consolidated_sorts:
                    if len(list(set(sorts[k].index).symmetric_difference(sorts[j].index))) == 0:
                        consolidated_sorts.remove(j)
    print('Consolidated Report Size: ', len(consolidated_sorts))
    consolidated_report = {}
    consolidated_val = {}
    for s in consolidated_sorts:
        consolidated_report[s] = master_report_dict[s]
        consolidated_val[s] = master_val_dict[s]
    return consolidated_report, consolidated_val
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if I understand your problem correctly, and even if I do, I do not know if this is faster, but wouldn't it be possible to create a dict, where you use the unique report index as key (e.g. using `frozenset`) and then the report key as value. It feels like a quicker way to build the unique list, but I may be off:

```
def report_diff_index(self,dnc_data,folders):
    master_report_dict, master_val_dict = self.report_orderer(folders)
    sorts = self.report_sorter(dnc_data,master_report_dict)
    print('Original Report Size: ', len(sorts))
    unique_reports = dict()
    for report_key, report in sorts.items:
        key = frozenset(report.index)
        # Alt 1. Replace with new (identical) repoirt
        unique_reports[key] = report_key
        # Alt 2. Keep first report
        if key not in unique_reports:
            unique_reports[key] = report_key
    consolidated_sorts = unique_reports.values()
    print('Consolidated Report Size: ', len(consolidated_sorts))
    consolidated_report = {}
    consolidated_val = {}
    for s in consolidated_sorts:
        consolidated_report[s] = master_report_dict[s]
        consolidated_val[s] = master_val_dict[s]
    return consolidated_report, consolidated_val
```

As you can see, there is also two options in the dict update, which depends on whether you want to keep the first found report or if it does not matter.

Insertion into a dict should approach O(1) therefore I would imagine this to be rather quick.

Comment: You cannot use it directly, but any immutable, i.e. hashable, data can be used as a key. `set`s and `list`s are mutable, thus not usable as dict `key`s, however, `frozenset`s and `tuple`s are immutable, and can thus be used. Thus, turning your indices to frozen sets make them usable as keys.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion! I implemented it using tuples as the keys, as brief testing showed their instantiation to be quicker than that of frozen sets, and it reduced the processing time of 100,000+ reports to 4.5 seconds!! Amazing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Dorian821 Glad I could help. As you mention, `tuple`:s are quicker to generate than `set`:s. Keep in mind, however, that for tuples `(1, 2)` is not the same as `(2, 1)`. Thus the order of the elements is important. That may not be a concern for your current use case, but in some cases it makes the `frozenset` a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but it looks like everything in:

```
consolidated_sorts = keys
print('Original Report Size: ', len(consolidated_sorts))
for k in keys:
    if k in consolidated_sorts:
        for j in keys[keys.index(k)+1:]:
            if j in consolidated_sorts:
                if len(list(set(sorts[k].index).symmetric_difference(sorts[j].index))) == 0:
                    consolidated_sorts.remove(j)
```

is just about finding unique reports. In fact, the iterations are redundant, because you first set `consolidated_sorts` equal to `keys`, then iterate those values and ask if they are in `consolidated_sorts`, which is where they came from.

If you simply want unique keys, you may try something like this:

```
def report_diff_index(self,dnc_data,folders):
    master_report_dict, master_val_dict = self.report_orderer(folders)
    sorts = self.report_sorter(dnc_data,master_tree)

    # New code to create unique set of keys
    unique_keys = set(sorts.keys())

    consolidated_report = {}
    consolidated_val = {}

    for key in unique_keys:
        consolidated_report[key] = master_report_dict[key]
        consolidated_val[key] = master_val_dict[key]

    return consolidated_report, consolidated_val
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue isn't with finding unique keys, but with finding unique  indices for the values in the dictionary. This is why I'm comparing values against eachother.

Comment: Are you using an `ordered dict` that you think your dict has indices? Or how is your `dict` structured? Also, I am surprised that this code currently works for you. What do you understand this line to be doing: `if len(list(set(sorts[k].index).symmetric_difference(sorts[j].index))) == 0:`?

Comment: @jack6e Not that I am Dorian821 but that line will, however somewhat contrived, compare the two lists of report keys and check for equality, independently of the key order in the lists. I would imagine a simple `set(sorts[k].index) == set(sorts[j].index)` would make more sense, but the result should be the same.

Comment: I suppose he is trying to do that, but trying to run that same code returns a TypeError for me, that the `.index` method, as a built-in, is not iterable. I wonder if he is actually trying to do something along the lines of `keys.index(k)` and `keys.index(j)`. Or he could be trying `consolidated_sorts.index(k/j)`, etc. I still cannot get past the idea that OP is trying to find "unique indices for the values in the dictionary" but not "unique keys", as if `dict`s had indices and not keys. Maybe the OP's confusion between lists and dicts is what makes this confusing.

Comment: thanks for the comments guys. the confusion here seems to be derived from the fact that the values of the dict are dataframes, not lists, consequently, the index is called on a pandas dataframe, as stated in the original post. granted, this might not be the best approach overall, just what I've got going at the moment.

Comment: @JohanL comparing the sets is obviously simpler and more intuitive. thanks. I'll try that. but I'm curious if there is a different approach overall. The answer below suggests using the indices as dict keys, but is this possible?